# How to assert number text in a class and type it in input field

Tags: text, cypress

here is the element of the difference below:

<td class="warning">₱ -10608.90</td> == $0

I am trying to assert the difference (10608.90 value) as per element above then type the text in counted input field

Counted   Diference

---          -10608.90

may i know how to code this in cypress?

Comment: [link](https://www.loom.com/share/4c3ae955b4c749a4bce4f627cdbba812)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the currency, try to split the string at the space character.

```js
cy.get('td.warning')
  .then($td => {
    const text = $td.text()                  // ₱ -10608.90

    const amount = test.split(' ')[1]      // -10608.90   
                                           // presuming number is negative

    // continue to use the amount -  note it is still a string
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try *invoke* function for that operation (I don't know the element's selector so I called the class "destination". You can change it for your case):

```
cy.get(".warning").invoke("text").then((textUsed) => {
    //Write it to destination selector
    cy.get(".destination").type(textUsed);
})
```